# Why doesn't TypeScript show an error when we assign primitive string to object String?

Tags: javascript, typescript

As I understand in TypeScript `string` is a primitive  and `String` is an object. Consider the following code:

```
let s: string = new String("foo");// ERROR 
let S: String = "foo";//OK
```

Why don't we get an error on the second line. We do show that we will use string object, but we use string primitive.

Comment: Related: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types

Answer (score 1):

The first line will error out because you're trying to assign a boxed type to a primitive type, which is *more specific*.

The second line will not error because you're converting a primitive type to a boxed type, which is *less specific*.

Going back to the first line:

```
let s = new String("foo");
console.log(typeof s); // object
```

The error description is quite on point:

```
'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
```

You can still do it if you do type assertion: TypeScript passes, and JavaScrip then *unboxes* the variable. I can't find a reason for anything like that however:

```
let s: string = new String("foo") as string; // OK
```

Interestingly, you can also do *conversions* with a slightly similar syntax:

```
let s: string = String("foo"); // OK
console.log(typeof s); // string
```

This is specially useful with `Boolean` conversions, for example:

```
const objectExists = Boolean(someObjectThatMightNotExist);
console.log(typeof objectExists); // boolean
```